# How to type currying function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm stuck with TypeScripting currying function.

I have function `useStore` from `'zustand'` library

```
export interface UseStore<T extends State> {
    (): T;
    <U>(selector: StateSelector<T, U>, equalityFn?: EqualityChecker<U>): U;
}
```

and i'm using it like this:

```
type Store<T> = [UseStore<T>, ...]

const createStore = <T>(opts: Options<T>)> => {
    ....
    const store: Store<T> = [useStore, ...];
    return store;
}
```

I wrote enhancer function

```
const enhancer = useStore => (selector, equalityFn) => {
    ....
    return useStore(selectorHelper(selector), equalityFn);
};
```

And i want to use it in my createStore function like this:

```
const store = [enhancer(useStore), ...]
```

Code is working but i can't figure out how to type `Enhancer` and `Store` correctly..

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  Ideally someone should be able to drop the code into their own IDE and the only issue present is the one you are asking about.  Good luck!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having a hard time typing the `StateSelector`

Answer (score 0):

You can do function overload. Have a look in the [Typescript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). It should give you some idea to to this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.